# How to increase index of dynamically added input onclick by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have a form, i have few fields want to add dynamically add, i want to change the index of each dynamically added input
Here is my html code.

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div id="hobies">
    <input type="text" name="hobies[]">
  </div>
  <br/>
  <button id="add_more">Add More</button>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<div id="tmp_hobies">
  <input type="text" class="hobies" name="hobies[]">
</div>
```

Here is my script code.

```
$('#add_more').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    $('#hobies').append($("#tmp_hobies").html());
});
```

Here is i want to add hobies[1], hobies[2] and so on...

Comment: For sending all those fields to server, `name="hobies[]"` is enough! Browser should handle that!

Comment: @undefined, you are correct, but next level i want use jquery validation, there i need unique name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sending all those fields to server, `name="hobies[]"` is enough, i.e. you can keep your code untouched. Browser should handle that!

In case you really need to do this, one option is:

```
$('#add_more').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const $o = $('#hobies input').last();
  const name = `hobies[${$o.index() + 1}]`;
  $o.clone().prop('name', name).val('').appendTo('#hobies');
});
```

Note that it doesn't use the `#tmp_hobies` element contents.

Answer (score -1):

var rowCount = 1;

```
 var count=0;
 function addMoreRows(form) {
 rowCount ++;
 count =++count;
 var recRow = '<p id="rowCount'+rowCount+'"><tr><td><input path="users['+count+'].id" id="users'+count+'.id" name="users['+count+'].id" type="" size="17%"  maxlength="120" /></td><td><input path="users['+count+'].name" id="users'+count+'.name" name="users['+count+'].name" type="text"  maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 5px 0 5px;"/></td><td><input path="users['+count+'].email" id="users'+count+'.email" name="users['+count+'].email" type="text" maxlength="120" style="margin: 4px 10px 0 0px;"/></td></tr> <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeRow('+rowCount+');">Delete</a></p>';
 $('#addedRows').append(recRow);
 }
```

Comment: for dynamic row creation please do the following